# VBA Subroutine that empties cells in a range

Tags: excel, vba, loops, subroutine

I have a code that I cannot seem to get working. I am trying to take the values within a range and reset these values with an empty string (""). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
Sub clear()
    Dim resultRng As Range
    Set resultRng = Worksheets("Search").Range("B4:B300")

    For i = 1 To resultRng.Count
    Dim emptystring As String
    emptystring = ""
    resultRng.Cells(i) = emptystring
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop:

```
resultRng.Value = vbNullString
```

Or maybe

```
resultRng.ClearContents
```